# Scala splitting a string by backtick

Tags: string, scala, backticks

When I try to split a string by backtick (`) symbol in REPL, it gives me an array of string output and the same was working during run time also with my jar file

Suddenly, the jar file code is not splitting the string by backtick

This backtick is the delimiter and it's being passed as an argument from a shell script

I tried to manually put backtick in split function in the code but below is the error for both cases

```
    val delimiter=args(0)     //this argument value is backtick (`),passed from shell during spark-submit command like spark-submit jarfile \`
    val FileContent="tablename`dbname`type"

    case class ABC(a: String,b: String,c: String)  
                       
    def parseFile(): ABC= {
      val Array(a,b,c) = FileContent.split(delimiter) //this is where its giving below mentioned error, its not splitting by backtick
      ABC(a,b,c)
    }

    val individualRecord = parseFile

    Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@a4b2d8f (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:926)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:935)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

if(delimiter == "`") println("yes") else println("no")
//above prints **yes**
//and below prints **backtick**
delimiter match {
      case "`" => println("backtick")
      case _ => println("not a backtick")
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code and examples of data raising the error?

Comment: @GaëlJ added the code block and error details

Comment: How do you _know_ that `args(0)` is what you expect? How have you tested it? Does `delimiter == "\`"` return **true**?

Comment: What does `println(s"->$delimiter<-")` produce? You also might try `delimiter.map(_.toInt).mkString(",")`.

Comment: @jwvh if(delimiter == "`") println("yes") else println("no") this gives yes
and println(s"->$delimiter<-") produce ->\`<-

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `delimiter == "\`"` but `fileContent.split(delimiter) != fileContent.split("\`")`. Something is amiss.

Comment: yea split is not working. when i do println("records - "+fileContent.split(delimiter)), it gives this, records - [Ljava.lang.String;@4678a2eb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238640/discussion-between-akm-and-jwvh).

Comment: I copied this into Scastie and it works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/M5G6d2KiQeqgHW8e0OSDEQ